# Tools for auto class translation WCF?

Tags: vb.net, wcf, wssf, translators

We are in the process of writing a WCF service using the same pattern as in WSSF. It has its service implementation which makes use of Business logic project to get the resources or save the resources using Data Access Repository. This is where the problem comes since we have to write a translator for translating Data Contract to Business Entity and Vice Versa. This translation is becoming tedious.

I am looking for a way (maybe using Reflection) to write one function to Translate Datacontract to Business Entity and vice versa.

Any suggestion is most welcome.

Thanks,

Raja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)

Comment: We're using AutoMapper on my current project with great success.  It's the industry standard way to do what it sounds like you're looking to do.